Error: contract runner does not support calling (operation="call", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.13.1)
I am trying to interact with an ERC20 standard token contract which is implemented with Openzeppelin smart contract.
Now I am trying to call allowance method with 0x address in the deployed contract on the hardhat local node to test whether it will revert or not.
This is the smart contract snippet:
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _approve(owner, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value, bool emitEvent) internal virtual {
        if (owner == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidApprover(address(0));
        }
        if (spender == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSpender(address(0));
        }
        _allowances[owner][spender] = value;
        if (emitEvent) {
            emit Approval(owner, spender, value);
        }
    }

and this is the test case I written:
  it("Should revert when owner address is zero ", async () => {
            const { helper01, helper02 } = await getNamedAccounts();
            const allowanceAmount = 129;
            const zeroOwnerContract = await simpleTokenContract.connect(ZeroAddress);
            await (zeroOwnerContract.approve(helper01, allowanceAmount)).to.be.revertedWith("ERC20InvalidApprover")

        })


zeroAddress value is "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
when I execute the test case I am getting this error:
     Should revert when owner address is zero:
     Error: contract runner does not support calling (operation="call", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.13.1)
      at makeError (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:694:21)
      at assert (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:715:25)
      at staticCallResult (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:330:15)
      at staticCall (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:303:30)
      at Proxy.balanceOf (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:351:47)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/00-simpleToken.test.js:81:49)


I tried with connecting the contract with different address (wallet) as well but still getting the same error.
If you can see the test case snippet I took two helper addresses.
I tried everything I know please help me to figure out what is causing the issue.

I tried the same code deploying to Sepolia testnet and the transaction got reverted successfully.
So I am thinking either hardhat don't support transactions with zeroAddress or I might be missing something to make it work with local node.
